# Regex for specifying a date format

Tags: regex

I have defined the following regex for a specific date:

```
(0[1-9]|1[012]|[1-9])[\/-]                             
(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0]|[1-9])[\/-]                 
(18[0-9]+|19[0-9]+|20[0-9]+|0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-9]|4[0-9]|5[0-9]|6[0-9]|7[0-9]|8[0-9]|9[0-9])
```

First line defines the month, second line the date and third year formats.

I am good with the limits for dates, months and years but I dont know how to reject mixed formats like mm/dd-yyyy or mm-dd/yyyy.

Can someone please help??

Answer (score 0):

You can match the first delimiter, then use a back reference to it.

```
 # /(0[1-9]|1[012]|[1-9])([\/-])(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0]|[1-9])\2(18[0-9]+|19[0-9]+|20[0-9]+|0[1-9]|[1-9][0-9])/

 ( 0 [1-9] | 1 [012] | [1-9] )          # (1), Month
 ( [/-] )                               # (2), Delimiter / or -
 (                                      # (3 start), Day
      0 [1-9] 
   |  1 [0-9] 
   |  2 [0-9] 
   |  3 [0] 
   |  [1-9] 
 )                                      # (3 end)
 \2                                     # Delimiter backreference
 (                                      # (4 start), Year
      18 [0-9]+ 
   |  19 [0-9]+ 
   |  20 [0-9]+ 
   |  0 [1-9] 
   |  [1-9] [0-9]       
 )                                      # (4 end)
```